# WPF checkbox problem

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, binding

I have a checkbox in my xaml which is bind to a property and even if the property is false, it is not making the checkbox disabled.

Here is the xaml:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="checkBox" Width="60">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox  IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsClickable}"/> 
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

viewModel.cs

```
    public bool IsClickable
    {
        get { return _isClickable; }
        set { _isClickable = value;
            PropertChanged("IsClickable");}
    }
```

And I m setting this property at the time of object creation.

And im binding the datagrid using itemsource;

```
 Datagrid.ItemsSource = ViewModels;
```

And I can see that the object collection of viewmodel does have that property populated as false.But is not disabling the checkbox.

Can some one tell me why please?

Comment: <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="checkBox" Width="60">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox  IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsClickable}"/> 
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
 Here is my xaml of checkbox

Comment: Are there any binding errors in the Output window of Visual Studio?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're binding the `IsChecked` property, but if you want to enable/disable the `CheckBox`, you need to bind the `IsEnabled` property:

```xml
<CheckBox IsEnabled="{Binding Path=IsClickable}" />
```

(you will probably need to bind `IsChecked` to something else, otherwise you won't be able to retrieve the checked state)